# Sequence of words in the non-question sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis, questions

I have certain doubts, shall we say, about which of the following is correct:

- I don't know where precisely you live;
- I don't know where precisely do you live.

For some reason I feel that the first one is correct, but I'm not sure about any actual rules governing the decision in this specific instance.

Would you please be so kind as to educate me what is the general guiding principle for such cases?

Sincerely Yours,
Adrianna W. McCrory

Comment: Hi Adrianna! If you are learning the english language, https://ell.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this question :)